# Append two arrays into a single binary file

Tags: c

I have two arrays that I want to write (actually append) both of them in a binary file so that I get the result `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. My following code does only the first part but it doesn't append the second part:

```
FILE *fp;
int sum1[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int sum2[10]={6,7,8,9,10};
int sum[10]={0};
int i;

// Write the first array sum1
fp = fopen("test.bin","wb");
fwrite(sum1, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);

// Write (append) the second array sum2 at the end of test.bin file
fp = fopen("test.bin","rb");
fseek(fp, 5, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(sum2, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);

// Show the result if both sum1 and sum2 are merged.
fp = fopen("test.bin","rb");
fread(sum, sizeof(int), 10, fp);

for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d, ", sum[i]);
}
printf("\n");
fclose(fp);
```

The result is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,`. which is not as I want. How do I modify the code to reflect my need? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
fp = fopen("test.bin","rb");
```

does not open `"test.bin"` for writing, `r` stands for "read".

You should use:

```
fp = fopen("test.bin","ab");
```

Here, `a` means "append". There's no need to seek to the end, append means you can only do appends so all writes will be at the end of the file.

Also you should error-check the I/O functions.

Comment: note that checking the I/O on `fwrite` would have shown that it wasn't writing anything.

Answer (score 1):

this part is seriously buggy:

```
fp = fopen("file.bin","rb");
fseek(fp, 5, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(sum2, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

- first, you're opening the file in *read mode*, so `fwrite` has no effect. Replace the mode by *read write*
- then your `fseek` offset is wrong, multiply by integer size or you'll write at the wrong location.

fix:

```
fp = fopen("file.bin","rb+");
fseek(fp, 5 * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(sum2, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

I just realized that you're just emulating "append" mode so there's a simpler way:

```
fp = fopen("file.bin","ab");
fwrite(sum2, sizeof(int), 5, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. `ab` is great idea. Having known about it before